# Exactly in the Middle between Samples with GL_NEAREST Filtering: What Does It Return?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, textures, interpolation

What value is going to be returned if 2D texture with `GL_NEAREST` mag and min filtering (and **no** mipmapping, i.e. there exists only 1 level) is sampled **exactly** in the middle between 4 texels?

Unfortunately, there is not a single note about that in the official documentation.

**Update:**

Actually, the whole cross looks pretty ambiguous to me. In the following figure I've drawn with `x` the ambiguous points (lines), and the 4 texels are denoted by `o`:

```
o---x---o
|   x   |
x x x x x
|   x   |
o---x---o
```

So which values are returned if the texture is sampled at `x`'s?

Comment: "official documentation"...are you talking about the [`man` pages](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/) or [the specs](http://www.opengl.org/registry/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading [Section 3.8.8 (page 175)](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec21.20061201.pdf) correctly it looks like `floor()` is used on both axes.

```
o4--xA--o3
|   x   |
x x x x xB
|   x   |
o1--x---o2
```

So all the `x`es would sample `o1`.  Except for `xA` and `xB` which would sample `o4` and `o2`.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by their notation: what are `u`, `v`, `w`, and `i`, `j`, `k`?

Comment: It looks like they define `i/j/k` on page 156.  `u/v/w` *seem* to be defined at the bottom of page 173.

Comment: @genpfault Coud you please explain why it looks like floor() ?

Comment: @Petrakeas: Equations (3.23)/(3.24)/(3.25) on page 175 use the floor function notation on the top lines.

Comment: thanks @genpfault! According to figure 3.10 at page 160, it seems that the center of a texel (texel denoted by the integers i,j), corresponds to half u/v values. Am I correct? 
If I am correct, u,v values that are exactly between texels have no decimal part. eg u=1 is exactly between texels i=0 and i=1. Using the floor function for u=1 we get i=1. Thus, it would sample from the neighbor right texel and not from the left one, as the answer describes.

Answer (score 2):

I read the sections of the spec in the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682838/941314) and it seems that the selected answer is wrong.

According to the spec when GL_NEAREST is used, the texture value returned for the specified (s,t,r) is the one of the texel having: i=floor(u), j = floor(v).
Note that the value of a texel (i,j) is the one with coordinates (u,v)=(i+0.5, j+0.5). See fig. 3.10 at page 160.

This boils down to the simple rule that given a sample point, the value of the closest texel is used. In the case where we sample exactly between 2 texel centers, the one on the right or top is used. For example if we wanted to sample at u=1 (which is equally distanced between texel 0 and 1 centers), then we would select i=floor(1)=1, which the texel to the right. The texel's center is at u=1.5.

So this is what would happen:

```
o4----x3----o3
|     x3     |
x4 x4 x3 x3 x3
|     x2     |
o1----x2----o2
```

I also performed a test using OpenGL ES, by sampling a color-coded texture at predefined s,t coordinates from within the fragment shader and it behaved as expected.